# git push -u origin master not working

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am at the very beginning of a Ruby on Rails course, and am simply trying to push my app to github. It hasn't worked, and I've been troubleshooting for 2 full days now. I can't get any support from the folks I bought the course from, which is frustrating to say the least.

These are the instructions I'm given...

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "First commit"
git status
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/stukdo.git
git push -u origin master
```

This is what is returned

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can't get this to work and have no idea what to do from here. I've googled those exact errors, I've tried everything and just don't know. Can someone please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Did you execute the `git remote add` line as you have pasted it here? Can you report the contents of `.git/config` in your project's directory? I can't imagine how `https` got in there...

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
`git@github.com:username/stukdo.git`
try 
`https://git@github.com/username/stukdo.git`

and also im not sure if this is a repository made for you that your supposed to use with those credentials, but if it is your own repository it should be 
`https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<repo name>.git`

with `<username>` replaced by your username and `<repo name>` replaced by the repository you are trying to push to

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first confirm that the remote was added using `git remote -v` .

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).